# std::sort order is from greatest to least when std::vector::reserve is used?

Tags: c++

Why does using vector::reserve change the behavior of sort?

```
std::vector<unsigned> xyz;
xyz.reserve(3);
xyz[0]=3; xyz[1]=1; xyz[2]=2;
std::sort(xyz.begin(), xyz.end());
std::cout<<xyz[0]<<xyz[1]<<xyz[2]<<"\n";
//312

xyz.clear();
xyz.push_back(3); xyz.push_back(1); xyz.push_back(2);
std::sort(xyz.begin(), xyz.end());
std::cout<<xyz[0]<<xyz[1]<<xyz[2]<<"\n";
//123
```

Comment: reserve only reserves memory for the items to be stored so that it won't have to reserve more space if the vector needs it later. It doesn't change the number of items that the vector thinks it contains. You have a zero size array that has space to grow to 3 items without allocating more memory but it's still a zero size array. You then access items beyond the size of the vector which is undefined behavour. Use resize() to actually set the size...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It has nothing to do with it. You are going into undefined behaviour with your code.

Reserve does not allow you to use reserved space directly like you do here:

```
xyz.reserve(3);
xyz[0]=3; xyz[1]=1; xyz[2]=2;
```

It just ensures there will be no reallocation upon insertion of the elements. You did not insert them, you used a syntax that skips bounduary checks. Hence, the container does not know the elements are in there.

You could use `at()` which is the bounduary checking version of `operator[]` and it would blow up.

The proper way to do it is to `resize` or insert elements properly (there are several ways like `emplace`, `push`, etc.)

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::vector<unsigned> xyz;
    xyz.reserve(3); // blows
    // xyz.resize(3);  // works
    xyz.at(0)=3; xyz.at(1)=1; xyz.at(2)=2;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've added some comment on your code:

```
xyz.reserve(3); // only revserve spaces for 3 elements, xyz.size() is still 0
xyz[0]=3; xyz[1]=1; xyz[2]=2; // UB
std::sort(xyz.begin(), xyz.end()); // There's nothing in xyz, so xyz.begin() == xyz.end(), so std::sort sort nothing here
std::cout<<xyz[0]<<xyz[1]<<xyz[2]<<"\n"; // UB again
```

Answer (score 2):

This code snippet

```
std::vector<unsigned> xyz;
xyz.reserve(3);
xyz[0]=3; xyz[1]=1; xyz[2]=2;
```

is invalid. You may not use the subscript operator if elements of the vector do not exist. Member function reserve does not create elements of the vector. It only reserves memory for future elements. You have to use `push_back` instead of the subscript operator in this case. Or instead of the reserve you could use member function `resize`. Opposite to reserve it indeed creates the specified number elements of the vector. For example

```
std::vector<unsigned> xyz;
xyz.resize(3);
xyz[0]=3; xyz[1]=1; xyz[2]=2;
```